# How do I fill specific parts in the image with Canny Edge Detection Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I only want to fill the middle crosswalk, not all the edges of the image. How can I do it?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

#Routine to fix 
def fixColor(img):
return(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
img = cv2.imread("walk.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
plt.imshow(fixColor(blurred))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 300)
plt.imshow(fixColor(canny))

(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
coins = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(coins, cnts, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(fixColor(coins))
```

Result:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Comment: You can draw contours based on their area,  perimeter or shape. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Did you view the image what I want as a result? Do you think its possible? Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code you shared and performed an additional dilation operation to thicken the Canny edge output

**Additional Code:**

```
kernel_ellipse = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, kernel_ellipse, iterations=1)

(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

coins = image.copy()
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
         cv2.drawContours(coins , [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

**Result:**

[image]

***Note:*** In order to fill the contour with a color of your choice, the `thickness` parameter within `cv2.drawContours()` must be -1.

Comment: @kenth You can also experiment with the perimeter feature

Comment: I spotted it. You are missing an edge. Can you fix it? It is on left side bottom.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Depends on the Canny edge output. If the threshold can be tweaked further it might improve